# Laravel view грузит JS 2 раза

Tags: javascript, laravel, view, framework

Есть view с вот таким кодом

```
<div>
123
</div>
<script>console.log(123)</script>
```

При загрузке страницы "123" выводится 2 раза в консоль. При этом в панели видно, что console.log(123) в коде всего один. Т.е. Laravel почему-то исполнил прописанный JS 2 раза(

Я надеюсь, что кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой) Потому что я мозг сломал уже) Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему нашёл. Как оказалось всё довольно просто и это мой Vue.js.
У меня есть первый div с #app (который оборачивал весь сайт) и vue работал от него.
В итоге у меня первый раз исполнялся из script, второй раз при new Vue({el: '#app'}) =)